# Android : Jetty's HttpClient not working with Https

Tags: java, android, ssl, jetty, cometd

I am working on an Android project in which I am trying to connect `HttpClient` to an `Https` endpoint. For this, I found out that I had to add an `SSLContextFactory` while instantiating. After doing that, when I run the code, I get the an error mentioned below.

**How can I setup `HttpClient` to work with https?**

Error log :

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLParameters; or its super classes (declaration of 'javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.customize(SslContextFactory.java:1382)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.newSSLEngine
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart
 at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.doStart(HttpClient.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start
```

Affected code :

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import org.cometd.bayeux.Channel;
import org.cometd.bayeux.Message;
import org.cometd.bayeux.client.ClientSessionChannel;
import org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient;
import org.cometd.client.transport.ClientTransport;
import org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;

import java.net.HttpCookie;

public class ConsoleChatClient extends Service {

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
BayeuxClient bayeuxClient = StaticRestTemplate.getClient();
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new SslContextFactory());


private void performConnection() {
    try {
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        sslContextFactory.setTrustAll(true);
        HttpClient localClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory);
        localClient.start();
        ClientTransport clientTransport = new LongPollingTransport(null, localClient);
        bayeuxClient = new BayeuxClient(defaultURL, clientTransport);
        // Below for use with Spring-Security post-login.
        bayeuxClient.putCookie(new HttpCookie("JSESSIONID", StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid));
        bayeuxClient.getChannel(Channel.META_HANDSHAKE).addListener(new InitializerListener());
        bayeuxClient.getChannel(Channel.META_CONNECT).addListener(new ConnectionListener());
        bayeuxClient.handshake();

        StaticRestTemplate.setClient(bayeuxClient);
        StaticRestTemplate.setHttpClient(localClient);
        httpClient = localClient;

        boolean success = bayeuxClient.waitFor(4000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);
        if (!success) {
            System.err.printf("Could not handshake for ConsoleChatClient with server at %s%n", defaultURL);
        } else {
            System.err.printf("Handhskare ConsoleChatClient complete");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm()` has been added to JDK 7. I am not Android expert, but perhaps you should use a more recent version of Android that supports JDK 7 ?

Comment: @sbordet I have JDK8...

Comment: I doubt you can use JDK 8 in Android.

Comment: @sbordet : Please check this screenshot : http://postimg.org/image/nrv6yl1kn/

Comment: @WeareBorg did you solve this issue and if yes then how? I'm currently in a situation where I need a sslContextFactory with the ceriticate I have in .pem format